# Drawing Video Canvas In Python

Tags: python, video-player

I am not really sure where to start on a project. I designed a channel for the Roku using Brightscript over the past several months.  I now need to design a similar project for a different device but using Python. I don't know a lot about Python, but from what I have read it looks fairly easy to learn. My question is in Brightscript I had to draw a canvas passing certain parameters like size, location and color. This essentially was the video player. In Python to create a video player, do you have to draw a canvas or the like? Brightscript comes with components like roVideoPlayer where the code passes needed information into this object. Are there modules for Python that can be imported that create the components? 
Thanks for advice

Comment: You will have to add more information about your target "different device", and its graphics interface capabilities, compatibility, and so on.

Comment: It will bascially be on the same lines as a Roku running a Linux os something like Raspberry Pi or CMX AML8726-MX Android. The box will be stripped down to os with only essential apps loaded.